# Need help identifying these 3 bags

Tags: set-identification, city

I got them as a gift but without the packaging. 
I only have three bags numbered 1, 2 and 3.

[image]

Can someone help me with the series number? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These bags are very likely the [Cargo Truck (60020)](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=60020-1).
[image]

Comment: llllllllllegend